# When changing the value of the cell, the field turns yellow, but if we return the value, the background does not turn white

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

When changing a cell, the field turns yellow, however, when I return the old value in the same cell, it should be white, how can I do this. Here is the source code

```
function onEdit() {

  var sheetsToWatch = ['кафедра', 'преподаватели'];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var matchFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
  if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
    }
  if (!matchFound) return;

  var rowColLabel = 
  sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()).setBackground('#faec15'); // #faec15 
}
```

Tried to get cell value and compare like below however it didn't work.

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheetsToWatch = 'кафедра', 'преподаватели';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var matchFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
    if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatchi)) {
      matchFound = true;
      break; // Выходим из цикла, если найдено совпадение
    }
  }

  if (!matchFound) return;

  var rowColLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), cell.getColumn());
  
  // Проверяем, совпадает ли значение ячейки до изменения с новым значением
  if (rowColLabel.getValue() === cell.getValue()) {
    rowColLabel.setBackground(null); // Убираем цвет фона ячейки
  } else {
    rowColLabel.setBackground('#faec15'); // Устанавливаем желтый цвет фона ячейки
  }
}
```